# CreateProcess() with I/O redirection: setting lpEnvironment disables redirection?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to port muon (a C99 implementation of meson) to Windows, and I am having a problem with one of its unit tests. This unit test calls python3 which launches a python script. I use I/O redirection to get the result. The python script, called `get-version.py`, is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('1.2')
```

If I call `CreateProcess()` with `lpEnvironment` being `NULL`, no problem, I correctly retrieve the version.

But, the unit test is also setting several environment variables for the child process. If I set `lpEnvironment`, I can't retrieve the version anymore.

Note that the code is not setting `UNICODE` (so I use the ANSI API).

The relevant code, from a test code you can [find here](https://gist.github.com/vtorri/85660e0de3683d0ceef04e45f2decac0) (see lines 154 and 155), is:

```c
char *env = "MUON_VAR=FOO\0"; // last nul byte necessary
res = CreateProcess("C:\\Documents\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin/python3.exe",
                    "\"-c\" \"C:\\Documents\\msys2\\home\\vincent.torri\\gitroot_64\\muon_gh\\mon_test/get-version.py\"",
                    NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, env, chdir, &si, &pi);
```

Does someone see what the problem is?

Comment: What about CreateProcessW?

Comment: That's unlikely.  The -c option is meant to execute a Python statement, don't use it to execute a .py file.

Comment: @HansPassant : removing -c has no effect. still no output with lpEnvironment set to something valid

Comment: On a side note, when using both the `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` parameters, you should specify the `.exe` name as the first token in `lpCommandLine`. This is explicitly pointed out in the [CreateProcess documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa). This is why I never use `lpApplicationName` and only ever use `lpCommandLine`

Comment: @RemyLebeau even if I run a batchfile ? the doc says to set `lpApplicationName` to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau anyway same problem if I set `lpApplicationName` to `NULL` and the `.exe` in `lpCommandLine`: no output if I set `lpEnvironment` to a valid value (like in my original post)

Comment: You probably need to copy your environment, append the addition to it, then pass it to CreateProcess.

Comment: @vtorri "*even if I run a batchfile ?*" - yes, any time you run an exe directly

Comment: @Luke or use [`CreateEnvironmentBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock)

Comment: I resolve my problem using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/changing-environment-variables#example-2), that is changing the current process' environment variable and setting `lpEnvironment` to `NULL`. I am not sure I can consider this method as a valid answer, though.